# How can enable multiple contact form in drupal 8?

Tags: webforms, 8, emails

I want multiple contact forms(different fields) in my drupal 8 site Like Webform module drupal 7.

I have tried to add multiple contact forms and i am able to number of contact forms with different different fields but at time only one form i can able to enable. Can i enable different contact form with different menu link?

Is there any alternatives to achieve this or i need to go for custom form?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each has their own URL. Check contact.routing.yml but pretty sure they are of the form contact/{contact_form} where contact form is the machine name. You can create menu links and aliases to these like any other path.